# I can't get the necessary characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In MS Access, I send a request to an API and receive data in Uzbek Latin script, including characters like G', Q, O'. Sh I need to convert them to Uzbek Cyrillic script, where these letters look like Ғ, Қ, Ў. Ш I've tried writing functions, but it didn't work. I read about ASCII, but there are no such letters in the ASCII table. How can I display them correctly in my field? I've been struggling with this for three days now! Thank you in advance for your help!

```
    Dim LatinToCyrillic As Object
    Dim Character As String
    Dim Result As String
   
    
    ' Create a dictionary for Latin to Cyrillic character mapping
    Set LatinToCyrillic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Add mappings for Latin characters to Cyrillic
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "A", "А"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "B", "Б"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "C", "С"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "D", "Д"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "E", "Э"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "F", "Ф"
   LatinToCyrillic.Add "G", "Г"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "H", "Ҳ"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "I", "И"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "J", "Ж"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "K", "К"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "L", "Л"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "M", "М"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "N", "Н"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "O‘", "Ў"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "O", "О"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "P", "П"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "Q", "Қ"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "G‘", "Ғ"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "R", "Р"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "S", "С"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "T", "Т"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "U", "Ю"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "V", "В"
   
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "X", "Х"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "Y", "Е"
    LatinToCyrillic.Add "Sh", "Ш"
   
    ' Initialize the result
    Result = ""
    Dim i As Long
    ' Iterate through each character in the input text
    For i = 1 To Len(inputText)
        Character = mid(inputText, i, 1)
        
        ' Check if the character has a Cyrillic equivalent
        If LatinToCyrillic.Exists(Character) Then
            Result = Result & LatinToCyrillic(Character)
        Else
            Result = Result & Character
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return the translated text
    TranslateLatinToCyrillic = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple series of consecutive replacements is adequate. Combination of two (or more) latin characters should be checked first.

```
Function TranslateLatinToCyrillic(inputText As String)
DIM R As STRING : R = inputText

R = REPLACE(R , "G‘" , "Ғ")
R = REPLACE(R , "O‘" , "Ў")
R = REPLACE(R , "Sh" , "Ш")
R = REPLACE(R , "A" , "А")
R = REPLACE(R , "B" , "Б")
R = REPLACE(R , "C" , "С")
R = REPLACE(R , "D" , "Д")
R = REPLACE(R , "E" , "Э")
R = REPLACE(R , "F" , "Ф")
R = REPLACE(R , "G" , "Г")
R = REPLACE(R , "H" , "Ҳ")
R = REPLACE(R , "I" , "И")
R = REPLACE(R , "J" , "Ж")
R = REPLACE(R , "K" , "К")
R = REPLACE(R , "L" , "Л")
R = REPLACE(R , "M" , "М")
R = REPLACE(R , "N" , "Н")
R = REPLACE(R , "O" , "О")
R = REPLACE(R , "P" , "П")
R = REPLACE(R , "Q" , "Қ")
R = REPLACE(R , "R" , "Р")
R = REPLACE(R , "S" , "С")
R = REPLACE(R , "T" , "Т")
R = REPLACE(R , "U" , "Ю")
R = REPLACE(R , "V" , "В")
R = REPLACE(R , "X" , "Х")
R = REPLACE(R , "Y" , "Е")

TranslateLatinToCyrillic = R
End Function
```

Or, use the following code in case of lost characters when copy/paste to VBA editor:

```
Function TranslateLatinToCyrillic(inputText As String)
DIM R AS STRING : R = inputText
    
R = REPLACE(R , "G‘" , ChrW(1170))
R = REPLACE(R , "O‘" , ChrW(1038))
R = REPLACE(R , "Sh" , ChrW(1064))
R = REPLACE(R , "A" , ChrW(1040))
R = REPLACE(R , "B" , ChrW(1041))
R = REPLACE(R , "C" , ChrW(1057))
R = REPLACE(R , "D" , ChrW(1044))
R = REPLACE(R , "E" , ChrW(1069))
R = REPLACE(R , "F" , ChrW(1060))
R = REPLACE(R , "G" , ChrW(1043))
R = REPLACE(R , "H" , ChrW(1202))
R = REPLACE(R , "I" , ChrW(1048))
R = REPLACE(R , "J" , ChrW(1046))
R = REPLACE(R , "K" , ChrW(1050))
R = REPLACE(R , "L" , ChrW(1051))
R = REPLACE(R , "M" , ChrW(1052))
R = REPLACE(R , "N" , ChrW(1053))
R = REPLACE(R , "O" , ChrW(1054))
R = REPLACE(R , "P" , ChrW(1055))
R = REPLACE(R , "Q" , ChrW(1178))
R = REPLACE(R , "R" , ChrW(1056))
R = REPLACE(R , "S" , ChrW(1057))
R = REPLACE(R , "T" , ChrW(1058))
R = REPLACE(R , "U" , ChrW(1070))
R = REPLACE(R , "V" , ChrW(1042))
R = REPLACE(R , "X" , ChrW(1061))
R = REPLACE(R , "Y" , ChrW(1045))
    
TranslateLatinToCyrillic = R
End Function
```